# ¿Se puede usar el REGEXP_SUBSTR que tome los numeros impares con el segundo argumento en SQL Oracle?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, regex, subconsultas, substr

Tengo el valor de una cadena concatenada con & que son ordenes con su cantidad

`orden&cantidad&orden&cantidad`

ejemplo:
`PXS-230&3745&PX-231&3265`

pero esta puede variar, pueden venir mas ordenes concatenada con su cantidad correspondiente

lo he logrado con la funcion

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(CAMPO,'[^&]+',1,1)
FROM DUAL
```

Pero solo he logrado extraer una orden, hay alguna forma de indicarle a la funcion que el segundo argumento tome los impares: es decir que en vez de poner 1 o 3 en el ultimo argumento poner que traiga los numeros impares y si hubiera otra orden por default tome 1,3,5

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(CAMPO,'[^&]+',1,3)
FROM DUAL
```

De antemano, gracias